# How to properly v-if and v-for nested object vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, v-for

I cannot render nested object content with v-for, there is a prop which contain object, but the div didn't show when i do v-if="prop". Please help how to solve it. Here is the syntax that i used for render:

```
<div v-if="statisticBrandBrowsers && statisticBrandBrowsers.length">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in statisticBrandBrowsers">
    <div>View: {{item.page_view.hits}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Props:

[image: prop inspected on vue dev tool]

Comment: Your `statisticBrandBrowsers` is an object instead of array so `statisticBrandBrowsers.length` is invalid. Better to have it as an array of browsers. Eg: `statisticBrandBrowsers = [{browser: 'Chrome', conversion: {}, page_view: {}}]`. Then you don't have to access the `index` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is inside the conditional rendering not inside `v-for` loop because the objects don't have a property called `length`, so you should do something like :

```
<div v-if="statisticBrandBrowsers && Object.values(statisticBrandBrowsers).length">
```

`Object.values(statisticBrandBrowsers)` will give you an array which has `length` property